# Pyschopy Script That Uses Primary Display Monitor

Tags: python, multiple-monitors, psychopy

I'm using Psychopy for some stimulus presentation and have written a script thats working well but always presents on my laptop monitor not the second monitor (even if that one is set to primary display). I know you can use the Monitor Center for this type of adjustment but I would like to save the script as an exe so if it is possible to utilize the Monitor Class to always use the Primary screen for displaying that would be ideal.

I'm struggling with this page, however, http://www.psychopy.org/api/monitors.html

**-->Does anyone know if it is possible to write a psychopy script to always display in the Window's Primary Display monitor??**

THANKS!

Comment: Not sure why this question has been labelled as "too broad". @jonas-lindeløv is a `psychopy` specialist and has been able to provide a very specific and precise answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `screen` keyword in `psychopy.visual.Window` and set it to whatever value works for you, e.g.:

```py
from psychopy import visual
win = visual.Window(screen=1)
```

See [the documentation](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/window.html) for `visual.Window`.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you, this does the trick : )